# Storyboard Stack View not connecting to View File (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode11

I'm using [this old tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1), trying to make a simple red button appear in a horizontal stack view programmatically. I created the StackView file and assigned it to the storyboard stack view's class. I followed the tutorial exactly but the button on the simulator screen and my print to console in the button's file isn't showing. Did linking files to views in Xcode change? Thanks.

[image: Stack View File where the button is made]

[image: Storyboard File where stack view's class is assigned to RatingControl file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that you are trying to set the buttons before the stack view layout. Try to move the `setUpButtons` inside the `override func layoutSubviews()` in the stack view

Comment: I don't have the function 'override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()'

Comment: Sorry I meant layoutSubviews(), I have changed it

Comment: I don't have that function either, look at my screenshots. Thanks for the help attempt but I solved it and posted my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, my bad y'all. I guess I had to have the `setupButtons()` function in both the `override init` and `required init` functions.

Lesson learned: when connecting views in storyboard to view files, functions in view files must be called in the initilizer functions.

Comment: init from coder is called for views that are initialized from the storyboard or xib, and views initialized from code are done using the init from frame initializer. Rather than writing it in both, you can simply decide where your view will be used and pick the init to write code in. However, implementing the init from coder is still necessary, as it's marked as required.